# Svg Tag Horizontal Gap

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two  elements that I would like to display side by side.

http://jsfiddle.net/m7y8h7wf/

```html
<div style="background-color:#000000;font-size:0;padding:10px;">
<svg version="1.1" width="50" height="1">
                            <g stroke="white" >
                                <line x1="50.5" y1=".5" x2=".5" y2=".5" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        <svg version="1.1" width="50" height="1">
                            <g stroke="white" >
                                <line x1="0.5" y1=".5" x2="50.5" y2=".5" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
</div>
```

It looks pretty good in firefox, but in chrome there's a noticeable horizontal gap between the two elements.

I've tried removing all the padding/margins that I can think of but it doesn't want to go away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem, wouldn't starting the second element at `x=0` rather than `x=0.5` tighten things up?

```html
<div style="background-color:#000000;font-size:0;padding:10px;">
  <svg version="1.1" width="50" height="1">
    <g stroke="white" >
      <line x1="50.5" y1=".5" x2=".5" y2=".5" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <svg version="1.1" width="50" height="1">
    <g stroke="white" >
      <line x1="0" y1=".5" x2="50.5" y2=".5" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, should have seen that!

Answer (score 0):

let just the second svg x1 value start at 0.

now it starts at 0.5 so 0.5 pixels away from left.

```
<svg version="1.1" width="50" height="1">
    <g stroke="white">
        <line x1="0" y1=".5" x2="50.5" y2=".5" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  />
    </g>
</svg>
```

see updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m7y8h7wf/1/

```
x1 = horizontal start value of the line
x2 = horizontal end value of the line
y1 = vertical start value of the line
y2 = vertical end value of the line
```

greetings timotheus